# Use a list of filters within polars

Tags: python-polars

Is there a way to filter a polars DataFrame by multiple conditions?

This is my use case and how I currently solve it, but I wonder how to solve it, if my list of dates would be longer:

```
dates = ["2018-03-25", "2019-03-31", "2020-03-29"]
timechange_forward = [(datetime.strptime(x+"T02:00", '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M'), datetime.strptime(x+"T03:01", '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M')) for x in dates]

df.filter(
    pl.col("time").is_between(*timechange_forward[0]) | 
    pl.col("time").is_between(*timechange_forward[1]) | 
    pl.col("time").is_between(*timechange_forward[2])
)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pass multiple conditions to [`.any_horizontal()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.any_horizontal.html)

```
df.filter(
   pl.any_horizontal(
      pl.col("time").is_between(*time)
      for time in timechange_forward
   )
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You haven't made your example reproducible, so it's hard to test this, but how about

```py
import functools
import operator

conditions = [
    pl.col("time").is_between(*val)
    for val in timechange_forward
]

df.filter(functools.reduce(operator.or_, conditions))
```

?

Comment: I did not know about the `operator.or_` function. That works nicely.

Answer (score -2):

I did it, by using duckdb with polars

```
import duckdb
sqlstrings = """
  ****
  ****
"""
print(duckdb.sql(sqlstrings).pl())
```